# inserting data into django db issues (nothing inserts)

Tags: django, database, python-3.x

I have the below code, trying to insert form data into the DB.

I don't get an error, but nothing inserts, can anyone advise me as to why?

*view*:

```
from .models import Todo
def create_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        creator = request.user
        assignee = request.POST.get('assignee') 
        task = request.POST.get('task') 
    i = Todo.objects.create(creator=creator, assignee=assignee, text=task, complete='FALSE')
    i.save(force_insert = True)
```

*model*:

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    assignee = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

*urls*:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.todo, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.create_task, name='index'),
```

Comment: You've got two url paths with are exactly the same. The second url will never trigger.

Comment: If I want the data to return on the homepage still, how would I set that up? Sorry, very new to it... Do I change just the name from index to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change your urls so that they are different:

```
url(r'^$', views.todo, name='index'),
url(r'^create/$', views.create_task, name='create'),
```

Now, when you make the POST request, or submit the form, you send it to `/create/`.

If you want to send the user back to the `index` page after creating the model, you can use [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def create_task(request):
    # save data ...
    ...
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: You're the best! Thanks